# Triggering event from timer compare channel on ATXmega when timer is set to single-slope PWM mode

Tags: pwm, timer, atmel, xmega, atxmega

I am writing firmware for an ATXmega. I have a timer configured in single-slope mode to output a PWM signal. I need one of the xmega's event channels to trigger in the middle of that signal. I thought I had it configured to do so, but I am suspecting that the event is actually triggering off of the period.

Some representative example C code:

```
TCF1.PER = 100;
TCF1.CCA = 20;
TCF1.CTRLA = TC_CLKSEL_DIV1_gc;     // timer will not run until this line
TCF1.CCB = 100/2; // middle of the waveform
TCF1.CTRLB = TC_WGMODE_SINGLESLOPE_gc | SWITCHING_SIGNAL_CHANNEL_ENABLE; // enable timer output to pin
// ... and then later ...
EVSYS.CH7MUX = EVSYS_CHMUX_TCF0_CCB_gc;
```

And then an diagram showing the situation and the desired and undesired behaviour of the event channel:
[image]

How do I get the event channel to behave in the desired way, and then verify that it is not behaving in the undesired way?

Answer (score 0):

After testing with an independent test setup, I was able to confirm that the above code does indeed create the desired behaviour in the event channel.